# Get events from a certain day with the javascript google calendar api v3

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

Hello my main goal is to grab all the events from a google calendar and display their name with the date (and time if available) underneath.  I am using the javascript google calendar api v3 and are running into troubles grabbing the date for each event.  Before I explain my problems further here is the current code:

```
var clientId = '200816328603.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyD3rbV__d8u6r9u5GioBU0oVwa-53YXRqM';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
  checkAuth();
}

function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true},
      handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  if (authResult) {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    makeApiCall();
  } else {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
   }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
  return false;
}

//document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary)

function makeApiCall() {

  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'pvhs.k12.nj.us_r6jaor04o80hpsaldf17civeio@group.calendar.google.com'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      for (var i = 0; i < resp.items.length; i++) {

        //---------nodes for html elements
        var title = document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary); //titles are undefined so I'm using the summary as title instead
        //var description = document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].description); //there are no descriptions apparently
        var date = document.createTextNode('Start: ' + resp.items[i].start.date + ' End: ' + resp.items[i].end.date); //resp.items[i].date returns undefined

        //---------html elements
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = resp.items[i].summary;

        var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.appendChild(title);
        div.appendChild(h1);

        //loop is to filter out all the undefined
        if (date.textContent != 'Start: undefined End: undefined') {
          var p = document.createElement('p');
          p.appendChild(date);
          div.appendChild(p);
        }

        document.body.appendChild(div);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Now resp.items[i].start.date and resp.items[i].end.date will return the date occasionally but sometimes just return undefined.  How else can I grab the date of the event then?

My idea to get around this was to loop through every day of the month and grab all the events for that day.  However when I tried adding the timeMax and timeMin parameters with the RFC3339 timestamp for the wanted day it didn't return anything.  Could someone provide me with an example for accomplishing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

In order to use timeMin or timeMax you need to set 'singleEvents' to true which I believe returns individual instances of reoccurring events instead of the event group.

```
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': 'pvhs.k12.nj.us_r6jaor04o80hpsaldf17civeio@group.calendar.google.com',
        'singleEvents': true, /* required to use timeMin */ 
        'timeMin': '2013-02-01T11:43:22.000Z'
    });
```

hope that helps.